# Can Gaussian distributed random variables map to spaces other than $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable mapping from $(X,\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ to an arbitrary measurable space $(X,\Omega)$. Could this random variable be Gaussian distributed even though I can't define its "distribution function" as the codomain is not $\mathbb{R}$? I have only seen the density and/or distribution defined in terms of real valued functions. How can a random variable to $(X,\Omega)$ be Gaussian if it maps to some arbitrary set $X$?

Comment: You may want to change your notations. What you are searching for is known as “Gaussian element”, a quick google search may help you.

Comment: @blamethelag when we talk about Gaussian random variables do we generally refer to only real values Gaussian random variables?

Comment: Yes. To talk about Gaussian variables valued in an Euclidean (reap. Banach) space we talk about Gaussian vectors (resp. element).